# Position element absolute to page within relative positioned element

Tags: css, position

Is it possible to position an element within a relative positioned container absolute to the document?

Following code:

```
<div id="container1" style="position: relative">
    <div id="container2" style="position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 5px">
        I will be positioned inside my parent!!
    </div>
    <div id="container3" style="position: absolute;">
        I would like to be positioned relative to the document. But how?
    </div>
</div>
```

I know that moving `container3` out of `container1` would be a solution, but let's assume that's not possible because I have no control over the template, only over the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No mate, sorry you cant. If you know how far your div is from the top, you can push it towards your spot using negative values, but it will always be relative to your parent div.

Comment: That's sad, I was hoping for another answer. But thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

you may assign a negative value to top and left attribute. i did not ever hear it waw possible to set absolute coordinates to child block wrapped by position:relative parent.